# Parsing an SMS date/time

Tags: datetime, sms, at-command

I'm reading SMS using AT commands much like in [this tutorial](http://www.developershome.com/sms/readSmsByAtCommands.asp). When I read the messages, I want to know how "old" are those SMS. The information at which the SMS was received by the SMSC is contained in the SMS, in plain text as:

```
+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+85291234567",,"07/02/18,00:05:10+32"
Reading text messages is easy.
```

How should I parse this `"07/02/18,00:05:10+32"` ? I mean, what does the +32 mean ? It cannot be a 32 hours offset from UTC.

Also, if an SMS is sent, say, from Japan to France, what would be the hour displayed when listing the SMS ? The hour from the Japanese SMSC ? From the French SMSC ? How can I convert them to UTC to reliably compute the time that has passed from the moment the SMS was sent (reached the SMSC) to the moment I read it ?

Not really looking for implementation specific answers here, but if it matters, I'll do the maths in shell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents the offset in quarters of an hour.

This link will help you to resolve the problem.

http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgsCommand2.asp

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

This answer confirms [eBusians's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35429380/23118), but shows how to arrive at the same conclusion using authoritative references instead of relying on random web pages (some are good, but many are not). The text on the linked web page is not incorrect, but it is only about the AT+CMGS command and not the AT+CMGL command as asked here, so then you have to guess/assume that they are the same format which is not a good approach.

---

The document describing the `AT+CMGL` command is the [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) standard (or your modem manufacturer's own specific product documentation). It defines the syntax as

```
+CMGL: <index>,<stat>,<oa/da>,[<alpha>],[<scts>][,<tooa/toda>,<length>]
<CR><LF><data>
```

And `<scts>` is defined as

```
3GPP TS 23.040 [3] TP-Service-Centre-Time-Stamp in time-string format (refer <dt>)
```

And `<dt>` is defined as

> 3GPP TS 23.040 [3] TP-Discharge-Time in time-string format:
>   "yy/MM/dd,hh:mm:ss±zz", where characters indicate year (two last
>   digits), month, day, hour, minutes, seconds and time zone. E.g. 6th of
>   May 1994, 22:10:00 GMT+2 hours equals to "94/05/06,22:10:00+08"

At this point I did not bother to dig deeper into the 23.040 specification as the 2 <==> 8 relation in the example is consistent with eBusians's answer and I have no reason to doubt its correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and references. Seems that time zones are specified in quarter of hours